# How to join two PySpark DataFrames on a common list column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have two PySpark DataFrames, df1 and df2, with a column named 'conditions' that contains lists of strings. I want to join these DataFrames based on the common elements in the 'conditions' column, where the entire list in one DataFrame matches the entire list in the other DataFrame.

Here's a simplified example of the data structures:

df1:

| id | conditions |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | ["abc", "apple"] |
| User2 | ["banana", "orange"] |
| User3 | ["cherry", "pear"] |

df2

| conditions | weight |
| --- | --- |
| ["abc","apple"] | 10 |
| ["banana"] | 21 |
| ["cherry"] | 15 |
| ["strawberry"] | 30 |
| ["banana","orange"] | 20 |

I want to create a new DataFrame that includes rows from df1 and df2 where the 'conditions' list matches exactly. In this example, the expected output would be:

| id | conditions | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | ["abc", "apple"] | 10 |
| User2 | ["banana", "orange"] | 20 |

I tried this, but the results are wrong.

`joined_results=df1.join(df2,on="conditions")`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are comparing two array columns there is a chance of incorrect results due to mismatch in order of items inside the arrays..For example `['a', 'b'] != ['b', 'a']`. To resolve this we have to sort the distinct elements in the arrays then use the sorted arrays as join condition

```
key = lambda c: F.array_sort(F.array_distinct(c))
result = df1.join(df2, on=key(df1.conditions) == key(df2.conditions)).drop(df2.conditions)
```

---

```
+-----+----------------+------+
|   id|      conditions|weight|
+-----+----------------+------+
|User1|    [abc, apple]|    10|
|User2|[banana, orange]|    20|
+-----+----------------+------+
```